# Filtering in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe resulting from loading a csv datafile using this command:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data_path, header=0, delimiter="|",dtype=object)
print df.head(3)
```

which has the following structure

```
ID      Val1      Val2
0       1         0.00000000
1       1         0.00000000
2       1         0.00000000
```

I am filtering out the Val2 rows equal to 0.00000000 with the following command:

```
df=[df.Val2 != "0.00000000"]
df.head(3)
```

Where I am expecting the results to be a dataframe with only the non zero values. However I am getting this error instead: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

what am I missing?

Comment: You want `df=df[df.Val2 != "0.00000000"]` also comparing floats may not work, you can use `np.isclose`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had a typo:

```
df=df[df.Val2 != "0.00000000"]
```

but fundamentally comparing floats is problematic, you can use [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to compare floats with a tolerance:

```
df[~np.isclose(df['Val2'], 0.0)]
```

Comment: is this also the case if I want to do > < comparison. For instance, what is the correct way to do df=df[df.Val2 > "0.00000000"]?

Comment: Yes fundamentally although `df[df['Val2'] <= 0]` would be correct the float precision may yield some strange results on edge cases which is where using `np.isclose` is better as you can pass a tolerance value

Comment: is is necessary to use `df` three times (no shorter/short cut)?   `df=df[df.Val2 != "0.000"]`

Answer (score 1):

`df.Val2 != "0.00000000"` returns a series (or a `list` essentially, which is why you got the error `'list' object has no attribute 'head'`) of booleans with `True` in the rows that meet the condition and `False` in the rows that don't.

As EdChum mentioned you need to pass that list back to the original dataframe in order to filter it and get only the rows that returned `True`.